# Why can't I download webpagetest using Docker?

Tags: docker

I tried to use 'docker pull webpagetest/server' to download webpagetest, but I received an error message that says: 'Using default tag: latest Error response from daemon: pull access denied for webpagetest/server, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.' I also couldn't find this image on Docker Hub. If I can't download it this way, what other methods are there?

And do you use webpagetest?

Thank you.

I tried searching on Docker Hub, but couldn't find webpagetest. I hope to use webpagetest locally.

Comment: Well, Docker says it doesn't exist. Why do *you* think it exists?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming problem though.

Answer (score 1):

The only two official docker images seem to be agent and tsproxy;

https://hub.docker.com/u/webpagetest

So I'd assume you're following an outdated guide, or got the wrong name for the server.